# Extract rows with specific phrase at specific column from text file using batch file in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, text-editing, extract

I have a text file (**epin.txt**) having >2 millions of rows.

Sample text:

```
182060045892569246925460002021    03560000000020000840000000000000ABDRGS00IN0000MMFADT265000 0917 P81 001
182060045892585476932540002021    03560000000100000356000000000000PFTSVS00IN0000MMTHRD285000 0997 P81 001
182071045892585476932540002021    03560000006905000356000000000000DFRTSS00IN0000BPSYFZ865000 0006 P81 001
```

I want to extract only those rows with "0600", "0610", "0620" at 4th, 5th, 6th and 7th column to a new text file.

So from the sample only the 1st and 2nd row should be extracted to a new file:

```
182060045892569246925460002021    03560000000020000840000000000000ABDRGS00IN0000MMFADT265000 0917 P81 001
182060045892585476932540002021    03560000000100000356000000000000PFTSVS00IN0000MMTHRD285000 0997 P81 001
```

I was able to do this using excel but only with file having less than 1 million rows.

Then I tried using **FINDSTR**:

```
findstr /B "0600 0610 0620" epin.txt > rf.txt
```

But this was only working for rows beginning with 0600 or 0610 or 0620;
and only with a specific filename.

Can it be improved a bit where it can look for specified phrases starting at Nth character and in any text/csv/flat files (like using wildcard in filename in the code epin***.txt)?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I am learning to use windows command prompt for text extraction/filename editing in batch. I have edited the post. I have tried findstr but it was not working as intended.

Comment: *"I am learning to use windows command prompt for text extraction/filename editing in batch"* - Arguably, you might be better served by learning this in [PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-7.1) or even [Python](https://www.python.org/). Batch can be quick and simple, but has quite a few quirks and drawbacks. Microsoft is even trying to nudge users away from CMD to a degree by making PowerShell the default in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try a character replacement (one at a time/column), in `Findstr`:

```bath
 String: 1820600
Replace: 182     to: ...0600
```

And you can use `.` to inform the search that you need in the desired column in `Findstr` command.

---

```bath
findstr /B "...0600 ...0610 ...0620" epin.txt > rf.txt
```

For multiple files, I suggest a loop using some mechanic like:

```bath
for /f ('where current_folder:file.txt + current_folder:file???.txt')do findstr ...
```

---

- Your code (in command-line) would look like this:

```bath
cd /d "Drive:\Full\Path\To\Files\Folder" & for /f delims^= %i in ('%__AppDir__%Where.exe .:epin.txt .:epin???.txt')do <con: %__AppDir__%Findstr.exe /b "...0600 ...0610 ...0620" "%~i">>rf.txt
```

- Your code (in bath file) would look like this:

```bath
@echo off 

cd /d "Drive:\Full\Path\To\Files\Folder"

for /f delims^= %%i in ('%__AppDir__%Where.exe .:epin.txt .:epin???.txt
')do <con: %__AppDir__%Findstr.exe /b "...0600 ...0610 ...0620" "%%~i">>rf.txt
```

---

<sub>**Obs. 1:** So sorry my limited English, hope you understand the answer/code..</sub>

<sub>**Obs.:2** I didn't quite understand this part:</sub>

> <sub>*Can it be improved a bit where it can look for specified phrases starting at Nth character and in multiple files (like epin001.txt, epin002.txt etc)?*</sub>

---

- Below is a suggestion that will count the files in `epin???.txt` in a `For /F` loop, and use the result `%%~i` in a loop through the range of numbers, to start from 1 step to 1 in 1 to total found in `%%~i`, and run the `Findstr` filtering in order/range `001-00%%~i`:

```bath
@echo off 

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /d "D:\Full\Path\To\Folder\."
>nul 2>&1 del /q /f /a: .\rf.txt

for /f %%i in ('dir /b epin*.txt^|%__AppDir__%Find.exe /v /c ""'
)do for /l %%L in (1 1 %%~i)do set "_n=00%%~L" && call %:^) !_n:~-3!

%:^)
if "%~1"=="" (
    endlocal & goto :eOf ) else 2>nul (
    <con: %__AppDir__%Findstr.exe /b "...0600 ...0610 ...0620" ".\epin%~1.txt" >>rf.txt
    ;exit /b )
```

---

Considering your last comment and also the last editing in your question...

> *Can it be improved a bit where it can look for specified phrases starting at Nth character and in any text/csv/flat files (like using wildcard in filename in the code epin***.txt)?*
>
> Yes

I can suggest to search with `Findstr` in a column (or starting at a specific column) use the dots in the same number of characters/column, or one or more characters of that form (`.*`).

`.*` Thus replacing `1` characters (`.`) or `more` characters (`*`).

```bath
@echo off 

cd /d "D:\Full\Path\To\Folder\."
>nul 2>&1 del /q /f /a: .\rf.txt

set "_my_files=.:*.csv .:*.flat .:epin*.txt"
set "_30th_column=.............................."
set "_find_in_30th=%_30th_column%0600 %_30th_column%0610 %_30th_column%0620"


for /f %%i in ('%__AppDir__%Where.exe %_my_files%
')do <con: %__AppDir__%Findstr.exe /b "%_find_in_30th%" "%~i">>rf.txt
```

---

#### Additional Resources:

- [`Where`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/where)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)
- [`Findstr`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [`Goto :Label` | `Call :Label`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [`If condition() else condition()`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [DOS - String Manipulation // dostips.com](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)
- Undocumented variables :

  - [`%__AppDir__%`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6137)  | [`%__CD__%`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6137)
  - [Environment](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)
- [How can I pass arguments to a batch file | *also applies to the function*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-a-batch-file)

---

Comment: It's working... :)